# replication checking shell script error

Tags: 12.04, mysql, scripts

I'm trying to create a Database Replication checking script which checks master-master replication but I'm getting error while executing it.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PATH

#Server Name
Server="Test Server"

#My Sql Username and Password
User=username
Password="password"

#Maximum Slave Time Delay
Delay="60"

#File Path to store error and email the same
Log_File=/tmp/replicationcheck.txt

#Email Settings
Subject="$Server Replication Error"
Sender_Name=TestServer
Recipients="tarun@example.com"

#Mail Alert Function
mailalert(){
sendmail -F $Sender_Name -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: $Recipients
Subject: $Subject

$Message_Replication_Error

`/bin/cat $Log_File`

END_MESSAGE
}

#Show Slave Status (Line I have edited later.)
Show_Slave_Status=$(echo "show slave status \G;" | mysql -u $User -p$Password) 

#Getting list of queries in mysql
$Show_Slave_Status | grep "Last_" > $Log_File

#Check if slave running
$Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: No"
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
Message_Replication_Error="$Server Replication error please check. The Slave_IO_Running state is No."
mailalert
exit 1
else
    $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: Connecting"
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    Message_Replication_Error="$Server Replication error please check. The Slave_IO_Running state is Connecting."
    mailalert
    exit 1
    fi
fi

#Check if replication delayed
Seconds_Behind_Master=$Show_Slave_Status | grep "Seconds_Behind_Master" | awk -F": " {' print $2 '}
if [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" -ge "$Delay" ]; then
Message_Replication_Error="Replication Delayed by $Seconds_Behind_Master."
mailalert
else
    if [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" = "NULL" ]; then
    Message_Replication_Error="$Server Replication error please check. The Seconds_Behind_Master state is NULL."
    mailalert
    fi
fi
```

This is the error message I'm getting.

```
tarun@devenv:~/Desktop$ sh databasereplicationcheck.sh 
databasereplicationcheck.sh: 40: databasereplicationcheck.sh: 60: not found
databasereplicationcheck.sh: 43: databasereplicationcheck.sh: 60: not found
databasereplicationcheck.sh: 49: databasereplicationcheck.sh: 60: not found
databasereplicationcheck.sh: 59: [: Illegal number:
```

Please Help.

Comment: Would be nice if add the error to your question.

Comment: I have added the error message please see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `echo "show slave status \G;" | mysql -u $User -p$Password 2>&` at line 37 gives an error back and we don't see this error, so you should print the `$Show_Slave_Status` variable in case of a fail:

```
#Show Slave Status
Show_Slave_Status=`echo "show slave status \G;" | mysql -u $User -p$Password 2>&1`
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo $Show_Slave_Status
  exit $status
fi
```

And then run the script again. It should now print you the error message of the `mysql` command and exit.

And add to the lines 40, 43 and 49 `echo` before the `$Show_Slave_Status variable`:

Line 40: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Last_" > $Log_File`

Line 43: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: No"`

Line 49: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: Connecting"`

Comment: what I'm trying to do here is I'm telling it to run the command `show slave status \G;` and take its output in the variable named `Show_Slave_Status` so that I can use this variable for further checking in mysql so that I dont have to execute the `show slave status \G;` command again and again. Any help?

Comment: Yes I know, but this command runs into an error. And you never print the variable so we never see the error to find out what's wrong. You can also type `echo "show slave status \G;" | mysql -u $User -p$Password 2>&1` manually in the terminal to get the error. But in this case you should set the 2 variable $User and $Password first.

Comment: I tried your code but still the same error. Now, I also have edited it like `Show_Slave_Status=$(echo "show slave status \G;" | mysql -u $User -p$Password)` and the output is stored successfully. But I don't know how to proceed now. I have edited in the question as well.

Comment: Hm, sorry, now I see the error... Add to the lines 40, 43 and 49 `echo` before the `$Show_Slave_Status` variable: Line 40: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Last_" > $Log_File` Line 43: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: No"` and Line 49: `echo $Show_Slave_Status | grep "Slave_IO_Running: Connecting"`